# How to reasonably use TLS in a setup without PKI?

Tags: tls

For an embedded industrial application, I want to use TLS to encrypt HTTP communication. I'd like to offer users easy to use options if there is no PKI readily available.

What are my choices here, to ensure best compatibility?

I thought about using TLS-PSK (users then would simply need to configure the PSK on both client and servir sides), but compatibility is a disaster. Most HTTP(S) clients (e.g. curl) or client libraries simply do not support TLS-PSK at all.

I also considered certificate pinning with server-side automatically generated self-signed certificates, so that no CA is required. Users would then only have to copy and import the certificate on the client side. The typical check of common name against the hostname would typically have to be disabled as well. Again, most HTTP client libraries don't really support this scenario.

Are there any other options available that I am missing?

Comment: There is a standard ([RFC 7250](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7250)) for using raw public keys with TLS.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds pretty neat, but software support for that is even worse. OpenSSL doesn't support it.

Comment: I think this is less cryptography and more applied security, i.e. more on-topic at [security.se]. Apart from that the restrictions of your use case are not fully clear. But if you need to use common HTTP libraries then there is likely no way around certificates, i.e. either with your own small CA or with self-signed certificates. Disabling validation of everything but the key will be a problem though since many can only disable validation at all (this is what you don't want) and not for specific features of the certificate. More information about your software stack would probably help.

Comment: Could you please elaborate "No PKI support available" further?

Comment: Again, please provide details about the software stack you need to use and other restrictions. All what you did so far is to reject ideas from yourself and others since they don't work in your specific environment without actually providing the restrictions. Based on this one could only speculate what works and what not and the risk that you will reject the next idea because it will not work either. In other words - in the current form the question is not specific enough , i.e. too broad.

Comment: Why cannot you generate your own CA keys and embed the CA public key in the trust store of your embedded applications ?

Comment: Do you need to authenticate the server to the applications, the applications to the server, or both ?

Comment: Internal CA or self-signed pinned certificate for the correct hostname is what most would do.

Comment: @A.Hersean That is what I could do, but ideally I want other clients to be able to securely use the API as well - part of the API is "public". The problem isn't only with the trust store, though. Most HTTPs clients don't really support this kind of certificate pinning. They want to check the certificate's common name against the host name, of the server, which does not apply to my use case.

Comment: @dietr Whatever you do, you cannot force clients (not under your control) to authenticate your servers if they do not want to. The only thing you can enforce is the authentication of the clients by the servers.